# Javascript Get URL is giving an error 404

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I get a GET http:/.../url 404 (Not Found)  when I am trying to get the URL from the javascript.
The error seems to come from the $.get("url").done in the script.

Do you see anything wrong with the code ?   I can't figure it out.  Thanks for any hint.

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
 }
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Panier/RemoveFromCart',
                 data: { id: $(this).data('id') },
                 type: 'POST',
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (result) {
                    $('#row-' + result.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + result.CartCount + ')');
                    $('#update-message').text(result.Message);
                    $('#cart-total').text(result.CartTotal);
                    $.get("url").done( function(data){ $("#TableContent").html(data); } ); <==
                 },                                                                        error
                 error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                 alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
             });
             return false;
         });
     });
 </script>
 <h3>
    <em>Details</em> du panier:
 </h3>
 <p class="button">
     @Html.ActionLink("Checkout >>", "AddressAndPayment", "Checkout")
 </p>  
 <div id="update-message">
 </div>
 <div id="table-content">
  @Html.Partial("TableContent")
</div>
```

TableContent.cshtml partial view

@model Tp1WebStore3.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel

```
 <a href="#" class="TableContent">
     <table>
         <tr>
             <th>
                 Produit
             </th>
             <th>
                Prix (unitaire)
             </th>
             <th>
                 Quantite
             </th>
             <th></th>
         </tr>
         @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
         {
             <tr id="row-@item.ProduitId">
                 <td>
                     @Html.ActionLink(item.Produit.Description, "Details", "Produit", new { id = 
                        item.ProduitId }, null)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     @item.Produit.Prix
                 </td>
                 <td id="item-count-@item.PanierId">
                     @item.Quantite
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.PanierId"> Enlever du panier
                     </a>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         }
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Total
             </td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
               <td id="cart-total">
                  @Model.CartTotal
               </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
 </a>
```

Comment: what `"url"` is supposed to be on `$.get("url")`? That's cenrtanly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
$.get("url").done( function(data){...}
```

It seems you're trying to use a variable named `url` which containst the url you're supposed to use. Instead, you're harcoding `"url"`  what causes `get` url to be `http:\\yourbaseurl\url` what is probably wrong.

Can't say for sure but it seems you're trying to do something like this

```
$.get(url).done( function(data){...}
```

Where `url` is defined someplace above.

Comment: I want to refresh my view since now it is partially refresh. Someone provide me the code but I can't figureout witch URL should go there.  Any idea ?  The URL should be something like this : http://localhost:49259/Panier   (the first part is variable, /Panier is a fix part)

Comment: I tried this, got no error but didn't refresh the page successfully (ie the deleted row is still appearing in the page  $.get("/Panier").done(function (data) { $("#TableContent").html(data); });